# Android - Joption based simple android program

Tags: android, android-activity

I have written a simple android program and i want to use it in android device.
somebody plss spare some little time to fix my code.. and also i dnt hav pretty much knowledge in android.

Main goal of the program :-
Input:- n= (any number from 1-9)
Input m= (printing index of the array) // if m=3  print a[3]=

according to IF else condition in program..

reorder the set of numbers 1 to 9 and store it in an array..

print the output of stored array

output :- a[m] = result

```
package com.example.starapp;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private Spinner firstSetNumbers,secondSetNumbers;
    Integer n,m;
    Integer[] a = null ;
    TextView result;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        firstSetNumbers= (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner_firstSet);
        secondSetNumbers= (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner_secondset);
        result=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView_result);
        firstSetNumbers.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            n=Integer.parseInt(firstSetNumbers.getSelectedItem().toString());
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });

        secondSetNumbers.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                m=Integer.parseInt(secondSetNumbers.getSelectedItem().toString());

            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });

    }
public void submit(View v){
    if(n==1) n=1;
    else if(n==2) n=9;
    else if(n==3) n=8;
    else if(n==4) n=7;
    else if(n==5) n=6;
    else if(n==6) n=5;
    else if(n==7) n=4;
    else if(n==8) n=3;
    else if(n==9) n=2;

    for(int i=0;i<9;i++)
    {
     // App is force to close in this step... 
    a[i]=n++;
      if(n==10) n=1;
    }

    nak(a[m-1]);
}

public void nak(int x)
{
    if(x==1) result.setText(" 1 = result");
else if(x==2) result.setText(" 2 = result");
else if(x==3) result.setText(" 3 = result");
else if(x==4) result.setText(" 4 = result");
else if(x==5) result.setText(" 5 = result");
else if(x==6) result.setText(" 6 = result");
else if(x==7) result.setText(" 7 = result");
else if(x==8) result.setText(" 8 = result");
else if(x==9) result.setText(" 9 = result");
}
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You never initialized `a`, so you get a NullPointerException when you try to do `a[i]=n++`.

Replace

```
Integer[] a = null ;
```

with

```
Integer[] a = new Integer[10]; // or whatever size you need
```